# S3 enable versioning affect on version-unaware code

Tags: amazon-s3, version

I'd like to turn on versioning so I as a human can browse the console and see the history of files (my code won't be interacting with versioning). but I'd like make sure that my current system doesn't break. None of my current code is aware of versioning. **Are there any cases where code that is unaware of versioning might break when versioning is enabled?**

One entirely invented example is if my code crashes when it sees the `x-amz-version-id` header when making a GET request. This sort of crashing is not a real possibility in my case, but it's an example of something I'd like to know about so I can be sure my system doesn't break.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, versioning should not break your code.

Normal API calls that don't refer to versions/versioning will simply see the latest version of each object and will not see deleted objects (even though they are still kept).